# How to find and copy file containing today's date in filename, the easiest way (e.g. cmd.exe)

Tags: cmd

I have one folder with 365 files named
01-01.mp3
02-01.mp3
...
25-08.mp3
and so on and I want to copy a file of "today's date" into another folder. Can I do it in Windows Task Scheduler via cmd.exe somehow?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
set today=%Day%-%Month%

copy "PATH\TO\FOLDER\%today%.mp3" "PATH\TO\SAVE\FILE\example.mp3"
```

Save the file as `.bat`